# mock repository in service

Tags: design-patterns, moq

I have a service and i want test without using the "real" repository, but a mock repository.
the main program

```
ServiceManager service = new ServiceManager();
Customer c = new Customer();
//set customer properties
service.Save(c);
```

the service

```
public class ServiceManager
{
    public bool Save(Customer customer)
    {
        Repository rep = new Repository();
        bool res = rep.Save((customer));

        return res;
    }
}
```

in test, i don't want save really the customer.
using mock, i can create the repository

```
var rep = new Mock<Repository>();
rep.Setup(x => x.Save(customer)).Returns(true);
```

but how can i call in test the service using this mock repository and not the real repository?

if possible i don't want create service like new ServiceManager(repository);

another way is use a factory of repository that return the mock if we are in test and the real repository when in real world, such as

```
public static class repositoryFactory
{
    private static Repository mockRepository;
    public static void setRepository(Repository rep){
        mockRepository = rep;
    }

    public static Repository getRepository(){
        if (mockRepository == null)
            return new Repository();
        else
            return mockRepository;
    }
}
```

in this case in test i use setRepository to save the mock.
which is the best solutions adopted in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way is to use *Inversion of Control* (that means that `ServiceManager` is no longer in control of creating `Repository`), commonly achieved by *Dependency Injection* (that means the dependency `Repository` is "injected" into `SericeManager`).

---

You seem to already know that, since you wrote

> if possible i don't want create service like new ServiceManager(repository);

You can, to achieve this, use an optional argument in the constructor of `ServiceManager`, like:

```
public class ServiceManager
{
    private readonly IRepository rep;

    public ServiceManager(IRepository rep=null)
    {
         _rep = rep ?? new Repository();      
    }

    public bool Save(Customer customer)
    {
        bool res = _rep.Save((customer));
        return res;
    }
}
```

to be able to simply use `new ServiceManager()` in your application and use `new ServiceManager(repositoryMock)` in your tests.

---

However, if you use a IOC-Container (like e.g. StructureMap), injecting dependencies is plain easy: you can leave the creation of objects to the IOC-Container and keep your `ServiceManager` and other classes "clean" of creating instances of dependend classes manually.

Answer (score 0):

> if possible i don't want create service like new ServiceManager(repository);

If this is an absolute requirement, you'll need to use heavy handed tools like `Fakes / Moles` to mangle a moled repository into your `ServiceManager` SUT.

However, since this is tagged `moq`, if you do decouple your dependencies (e.g. via Setter constructor injection), then you can unit test and `Mock` in isolation. Its a small overhead to make for testable code.

```
public class ServiceManager
{
    private readonly Repository _repository;

    public ServiceManager(Repository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public bool Save(Customer customer)
    {
        bool res = _repository.Save((customer));

        return res;
    }
}
```

And your unit test will now be able to create the `ServiceManager` (the SUT) and inject the Mocked repository.

And even better would be to abstract repository into an interface, `IRepository`, and then reduce the dependency of `ServiceManager` to `Repository` to an interface. Your moq repo is then `var rep = new Mock<IRepository>();` and the dependency becomes `private readonly IRepository _repository;`.